# Fibonacci - six most significant digits (right most) of very large n numbers

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm trying to efficiently calculate the nth Fibonacci value that can be very large by only retaining the six right most digits. For example fib(1000000) would return only 546875.

I'm aware of some of the recursive matrix exponentiation algorithms and I have been testing an O(log n) implementation like below -

```
def solution(n):
    fibs = {0: 0, 1: 1}

    def fib(n):
    # recursive helper function
        if n in fibs: 
            return fibs[n]
        if n % 2 == 0:
            fibs[n] = ((2 * fib((n / 2) - 1)) + fib(n / 2)) * fib(n / 2) % 1000000
            return fibs[n]
        else:
            fibs[n] = (fib((n - 1) / 2) ** 2) + (fib((n+1) / 2) ** 2) % 1000000
            return fibs[n]

    answer = fib(n)
    return answer % 1000000
```

All of the answers seem to work until n = 1000000. Should all the later exponents of 10 return the same answer? 10^k where k = [7, 8, 9, 10...] all return 546875 (the value of a million). I assume they should as these values have the same remainder of zero when you modulus them by 10^6. So I'm wondering if this implementation is correct?

Comment: Why are there `% 1000000` on lines 8, 11 and 15?

Comment: @galaxy001 he's keeping the 6 right-most digits

Comment: I see the millionth FIB seq number ending in '484376' ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did some simple code to prove/disprove your current theorem, and I stumbled upon this particular pattern: the Fibonacci sequence for the last 6 digits of the code seems to repeat every 1.5 million sequences.

This is part of the reason why the values at 1 million, 10 million, 100 million, etc. matches; 10 million - 9 million = 1 million, but 9 million = 6 * 1.5 million.

So, to answer your question, all you need to implement in your code is to first modulus n by 1,500,000, then calculate your answer, eg.:

`answer = fib(n%1500000)`

I've provided the code I used to find when the modulos repeat (find_repeating_length) as well as the function to check that the modulo is working as intended (check) below.

Hope that helps!

```
def solution(n):
    fibs = {0: 0, 1: 1}

    def fib(n):
        # simple linear-time fib function
        if n in fibs:
            return fibs[n]
        fibs[n] = (fibs[n-1]+fibs[n-2]) % 1000000
        return fibs[n]

    def find_repeating_length():
        find_number = [0, 1] # find these two numbers of the sequence
        for i in range(0, 10000001):
            n_0 = fib(i)
            if (n_0 in find_number):
                print(str(n_0) + ":" + str(i))

    def check(): # check that first 10,000,000 nums follow sequence
        for i in range(2, 10000001): 
            n_0 = fib(i)
            if (i >= 1500000):
                left = n_0
                right = fib(i - 1500000)
                # if (left == right):
                #    print("Success at " + str(i) + " Values: " +
                #          str(n_0))
                if (left != right):
                    return("Fail at " + str(i) + " Values: " +
                           str(n_0) + ":" + str(right))

            return "Success, repeats"
    find_repeating_length()
    print(check())


solution()
```

Outputs (slightly formatted, output in value:sequence format):

> 0:0 
>   1:1
>   1:2
>   0:750000
>   1:1499999
>
> 0:1500000
>   1:1500001
>   1:1500002
>   0:2250000
>   1:2999999
>
> 0:3000000
>   1:3000001
>   1:3000002
>   0:3750000
>   1:4499999
>
> 0:4500000
>   1:4500001
>   1:4500002
>   0:5250000
>   1:5999999
>
> 0:6000000
>   1:6000001
>   1:6000002
>   0:6750000
>   1:7499999
>
> 0:7500000
>   1:7500001
>   1:7500002
>   0:8250000
>   1:8999999
>
> 0:9000000
>   1:9000001
>   1:9000002
>   0:9750000
>
> Success, repeats